# Custom module issue

Tags: module, magento-1.7

I tried creating one new module. For that i created indexController, config.xml, block, layout and other required files, even though i am unable to view the message that i wrote in my block file. Whenever the url is fired (http://mydomain.com/foobar/) the output "it is from foo bar" should be displayed, but at the moment it is not working.

```
My indexController.php code :

class Foo_Bar_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}

Code related to block :

class Foo_Bar_Block_News extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function fetchRow()
    {               
        echo "it is from foo bar";      
    }
}

code related to config.xml :

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Foo_Bar>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Foo_Bar>
    </modules>   
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <foobar>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Foo_Bar</module>
                    <frontName>foobar</frontName>
                </args>
            </foobar>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <bar>
                    <file>foobar.xml</file>
                </bar>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <!--<events>
            <catalog_product_load_after>
                <observers>
                    <foo_bar>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>foo_bar/observer</class>
                        <method>catalogProductLoadAfter</method>
                    </foo_bar>
                </observers>

            </catalog_product_load_after>
        </events>-->
    </frontend>
    <global>
    <blocks>
            <foobar>
                <class>Foo_Bar_Block</class>
            </foobar>
        </blocks>            
    </global>
</config>


code related to layout.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="content">
        </reference>
    </default>
    <foobar_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="foobar/news"  name="news_test" template="bar/check.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </foobar_index_index>
</layout>

Code related to template file

<?php
echo $this->fetchRow()
?>
```

Any help realted to this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this issue in my case is to Disable the compilation from admin. Everything else is fine. The desired output is obtained after disabling the compilation from admin.

To disable compilation login to admin side of your magento project and then go to system>>Tools>>Compilation and then click on disable button to disable the compilation.